# How to convert htaccess to NGINX?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

Please, tell me how to convert htaccess to NGINX on this example.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico)(\?|$) - [L,NC,R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache makes things look a bit complex. But same config in Nginx is very simple

```
root /var/www/html;

location ~* \.(js|css|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico)(\?|$) {
   try_files $uri =404;
}

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php {
   # <your fastcgi php handling config>
}
```